# webpack-dev-server serves one-version-old bundle

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

I am using Webpack to build an Angular 2 AOT app (see config below). When I just run `webpack` everything works fine. When I use `webpack-dev-server`, it works fine for the first page load, but from then on the bundle is always one version old.

For example, when I start up the server with an Angular component template containing `<h1>hello</h1>` I see "hello" as expected. When I then change the template to `<h1>hello world</h1>`, the page reloads but still only reads "hello" (and the console says `[WDS] Nothing changed.`) When I then change the template *again* to `<h1>goodbye world</h1>`, the page reloads but reads "hello world" as it should have on the previous reload.

This delay does not happen with `index.html` (even though I am using `html-webpack-plugin`), only with TypeScript files and Angular templates (which are compiled to TypeScript files). It also does not happen with `webpack --watch`, only with `webpack-dev-server`.

My `webpack.config.js`:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const ngToolsWebpack = require("@ngtools/webpack");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: "./src/main.ts",
        vendor: ["@angular/core", "@angular/common", "@angular/platform-browser"],
        polyfill: ["zone.js/dist/zone.js"],
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/dist",
        filename: "[name].js",
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".js"],
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.html$/, use: "raw-loader" },
            { test: /\.css$/, use: "raw-loader" },
            { test: /\.ts$/, use: "@ngtools/webpack" },
        ],
    },

    plugins: [
        new ngToolsWebpack.AotPlugin({
            tsConfigPath: "./tsconfig.json",
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            names: ["vendor", "polyfill"],
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "src/index.html",
        }),
    ],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `chunkhash` ?

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const ngToolsWebpack = require("@ngtools/webpack");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: "./src/main.ts",
        vendor: ["@angular/core", "@angular/common", "@angular/platform-browser"],
        polyfill: ["zone.js/dist/zone.js"],
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/dist",
        filename: "[name].[chunkhash].js",
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".js"],
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.html$/, use: "raw-loader" },
            { test: /\.css$/, use: "raw-loader" },
            { test: /\.ts$/, use: "@ngtools/webpack" },
        ],
    },

    plugins: [
        new ngToolsWebpack.AotPlugin({
            tsConfigPath: "./tsconfig.json",
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            names: ["vendor", "polyfill", "manifest"],
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "src/index.html",
        }),
    ],
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That doesn't change anything- I've tried refreshing the browser, disabling its cache, etc. but it seems the disconnect is not between the browser and the server, but the server and the build.

Comment: Well, I just shared what worked for me. I had the same issue last time. You could try it , though. But that's how it worked for my case.

Comment: I did try it- didn't mean to make it sound like I was just dismissing the idea.

Comment: I agree. I think there's something between the server and the build.